Avoid shared memory between ASP.NET Core integration tests
I am writing integration tests for an ASP.NET Core application using NUnit. I observed a weird behaviour in my tests, were it seems as if all tests would share the same static properties inside my SUT.
I am using WebApplicationFactory to bootstrap my app and interact with it. My assumption was that I was using a 'fresh' instance of my app per WebApplicationFactory, and I was using one factory per test...
I created a minimal reproducible example, where I just have a static int field that is incremented at startup. An endpoint returns the value of the field.
My test gets repeated multiple times and is expected to always return 1. But as you can expect, it fails during the second run.
Program.cs:
internal class Program
{
    private static int a = 0;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var app = builder.Build();

        a++;
        app.MapGet("/test", () => a);
        app.Run();
    }
}

Unit test:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        [Repeat(3)]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
            var client = factory.CreateClient();
            var res = await client.GetAsync("/test");
            var number = int.Parse(await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            Assert.That(number, Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
    }
}

I am sure it has something to do with how WebApplicationFactory starts up the program, but it is still very unexpected and there was no mention about it when I read the docs.
Maybe it has something to do with me using NUnit instead of xUnit as in the docs? But then how does the behaviour of NUnit affect this?
I also tried using NUnits [NonParallelizable] to make sure the tests are run sequentially (this will be required anyway), and in my non-sample project I was using one class per test.
I spotted this behaviour, because I was registering ClassMaps with BsonClassMap at startup and I got an error about duplicate keys in my tests.
I am mostly looking for an answer on how to run my tests in a way, that they do not share state. I am also curious why this behaviour is even happening and if it is intended or not.

I dived a bit into WebApplicationFactory and saw that on CreateClient he checks if the TestServer is running and starts it up when necessary. During every test run, the TestServer was null and was booted up for each test. So I am either completely going off the rails or this issue lies inside the WebApplicationFactory

Static code should be stateless, and you are experiencing the results of when this is not the case. Aside from that, research [TestFixture] attribute in the docs and see how it can be used for creating integration tests.

WebApplicationFactory for minimal hosting basically runs Assembly.EntryPoint for every instance factory instance (which is your Main method) hence you will have your a++; invoked for every created and "started" instance of the factory (it includes calls like CreateClient, or Services or Server) and since a is a static field it will be shared through the whole app lifetime (basically by definition).
There are at least the following options:

Move from using statics to singleton services. I.e. encapsulate a in some service, register it as singleton and resolve where appropriate. Arguably it is a better approach in general case.

Use a single instance of WebApplicationFactory for all tests (so the setup is performed only a single time). For example using OneTimeSetUp combined with root fixture. For example adding something like the following to the root namespace of the test project (see the SetUpFixture docs):
[SetUpFixture]
public class GlobalFixture
{
    public static WebApplicationFactory<Program> ApplicationFactory;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup() => ApplicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();

    [OneTimeTearDown] 
    public void TearDown() => ApplicationFactory.Dispose();
}

And using GlobalFixture.ApplicationFactory where needed.

In some cases you can workaround by moving managing a to static constructor (add it to your Program class).

Another hacky approach would be to modify the entrypoint (the Program.Main) with some conditional logic (possibly via introducing another static field), something like if(a == 0) a++;.



My assumption was that I was using a 'fresh' instance of my app per WebApplicationFactory

It is using a fresh instance (which I would argue actually is proved by the test failing on the second run) but you still have the same static field shared for the whole process.

Maybe it has something to do with me using NUnit instead of xUnit as in the docs? But then how does the behaviour of NUnit affect this?

As you can see it is not NUnit per se.

Well I can't really move from statics to a singleton as it is not my code that stores the configuration inside static fields. As stated in the question, this comes from the MongoDB C# BsonMapper stuff. My only solution I saw was to 'mock' the configuration of MongoDB and have my test implementation make sure it get's configured only once. But with my integration tests I try not to mock, as I want to test the integration of my app with my DB and stuff (basically all the stuff I miss in the unit tests).

Also it makes me very uncomfortable ever having a mutable static field as it could cause deviating behaviour between tests and running it for real. But I feel like this deviation shouldn't exist. I expected the WebApplicationFactory to start up a new process instead of keeping everything in the same space

@Ascendise "this comes from the MongoDB C# BsonMapper stuff" - without seeing actual repro it is hard to tell, but the recommend approach with static ctor might do the trick. "I expected the WebApplicationFactory to start up a new process" - why? "Also it makes me very uncomfortable ever having a mutable static field" - arguably you should avoid mutable static fields in majority of situations.

without seeing actual repro it is hard to tell
The repro I provided was mostly to show the behaviour I observed. The Mongo stuff is how I saw it.
The reason I thought it is done like this, was because I thought it tried to spin up the application in itself for you to interact with inside the test. Or mainly, I didn't think about any static stuff that could get persisted by some library I use that could cause issues, because I was thinking on the application level, as you'd do when running integration tests. (cont)

When writing unit tests, I would obviously expect changes to static fields to persist between the tests

@Ascendise can you please add the actual code/setup. What is BsonMapper? How do you use it? Again - points 3 and 4 arguably should fix your issue if the first two are not feasible.

Well at this point I know how to proceed. My confusion was mainly about how WebApplicationFactory spins up the SUT and not about how to avoid static state. And I was mostly critisising that it felt a bit unexpected that in memory state was persisted between, what was supposed to be, simulated app runs. But thats my problem :P

Your are already using a single web application per test.
Your test is wrong. You are getting a new instance of the web application every time. But you made them all look at the same static variable. It's the same assembly / static Program class after all.
As suggested in comments, try it with a singleton and you'll find that it's giving you different results.
I'd suggest you keep using a web application per test, as this offers better isolation. I'd just move the code into [SetUp] and [TearDown] methods if you want to clean it up a bit. And maybe also adding this to your class: [FixtureLifeCycle(LifeCycle.InstancePerTestCase)].

The problem has nothing to do with NUnit or xUnit. In fact it is normal behaviour of static, which is bound to the process (or more exactly to the app-domain), instead of a specific instance of your Program-class. As all your tests are executed by the same process (some test-frameworks also allow for multiple processes here for better isolation), they also share the same static objects.
So the actual problem here is: how does one "reset" these static objects in a deterministic way?
As already mentioned your tests all run in the same app-domain, so there's no way to reset them on process-end. You need to manually reset the objects yourself to their default- or whatever-value. There are many ways to achieve this, as provided in the other answers. Another pretty general yet dirty way is to use reflection to get access to the static variables and set them to whatever you like.
This may in particular be a good start for testing your legacy-code which you want to modify as less as possible. E.g.:
[TearDown] // will be executed after every test
public void TearDown()
{
    var a = typeof(Program).GetField("a", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    a.SetValue(null, default(int));
}

However the test is very fragile. As soon as you rename the static variable or change it to a property, make it internal or whatever not, your tests will fail. So you should consider to refactor your code to somehow inject your dependencies from the outside using your DI-container. You should also consider to hide these dirty lines into some SetupTest-method, which you can rewrite as soon as possible.
